# Why is ~0 a Sequence of 1s

Tags: bitwise-operators

Why is `~0` a sequence of `1` bits and not just a single bit? Where do the extra `1` bits come from? Does this mean `~1` a sequence of `0` bits or just a single `0` bit?

My understanding was that the `~` operator is applied on the specific bits mentioned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

because `0` in the chosen representation (2's complement) is a sequence of `0`s, applying the bitwise NOT on it will naturally result in a sequence of `1`s

`1` is a sequence of `0`s followed by a single `1`

Remember that a computer will use all bits available to represent a number in a variable. In other words if you have a 64 bit variable then all 64 bits will be in use even if 90% of them are `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't thinking about 0 being the same as 00000...0. So does that mean ~1 (say 1 is 0000001) becomes 0 or 1111110?

Comment: @clicky 1111110. Those other bits don't disappear when you store 1, they are merely set to zero and hence affected by `~`.

Comment: +1 for figuring out the actual misconception leading to the question.

Answer (score 41):

Because that is what `~` does.

It flips the bits of the operand. If your language of choice treats that literal `0` as a byte value, it is essentially:

```
00000000
```

When the bites are flipped using the `~` (bitwise NOT), the result is:

```
11111111
```

In the same way that `~10` would turn:

```
00001010
```

To:

```
11110101
```

Comment: Ah. `0` is the same as `000000...0`, obvious but didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: @clicky - yeah, you need to think about how the computer represents the value internally.